# How can I perform an ordered merge with RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm performing 3 HTTP requests. I want to fire all simultaneously, wait for all to complete, then merge the three requests while preserving the order of the sequence. Let's say I have the requests `r1`, `r2` and `r3` and I want to process the results in that order. I've attempted this:

```
Observable<HttpResponse> r1, r2, r3;
Observable<List<HttpResponse>> merged = Observable.merge(r1, r2, r3).buffer(3);
```

In this case there is no guarantee that r3 is index 2 in the returned list.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current RxJava snapshot contains a `concatMapEager` that will run its sources immediately and join them one after the other. It will be part of 1.0.15 but I don't know when Netflix will release it. If you don't want to depend on a snapshot then take [the source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/OperatorEagerConcatMap.java) code and lift it manually into your sequence.